# I've got a .txt file with a few lines. I have to remove all the lines with the letter "a" from it and write it to another file. How do I do it?

Tags: python

#4. Write a Python program to create a text file, “Book.txt”, which has a few lines in it. Remove all the lines that contain an ‘a’ and move it to another file

```
def creation():
    f1=open("Book.txt","w")
    f1.close()
    f1=open("Book.txt","r+")
    while True:
        content=input("enter the line")
        f1.write(content)
        choice=input("would you like to add more? y/n?")
        if choice in "Nn":
            f1.close()
            break

def aim():
    f1.open("Book.txt"."r+")
    while f1:
        line=f1.readline().split()
        for i in line:
        for j in i:
                if "a" in j:
                    f2=open("NewBook.txt","w")
                    f2.close()
                    f2=open("NewBook.txt","r+")
                    f2.write(line)
            


#This is what I've done till now, I know it's faulty.....Please give an elaborated #answer :)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, and it seems you're overthinking it. Your inclusion of the `creation` function seems irrelevant to the question.

Iterate through the lines in the input file. If a line dopes not contain an `"a"`, write it to the output file.

Using `with` saves you the hassle of explicitly closing the file.

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as infile:
  with open("file2.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
      if not "a" in line:
        outfile.write(line)
```